# Edit JDBC connection string in Saiku

Tags: jdbc, olap, pentaho, mondrian, saiku

I am using Microsoft SQL Server as database for my web application. I'd like to use Saiku as part of the application. I found the solution to set up the JDBC connection string as below:

```
type=OLAP
name=foodmart
driver=mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jDriver


location=jdbc:mondrian:Jdbc=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=foodmart;Catalog=res:warehouses/FoodMart.xml;JdbcDrivers=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver; username=sa
password=XXXX
```

Anyway, I don't know which file in the package I downloaded (Saiku Server 2.4 (Including Foodmart DB)) is for changing the connection string as I mentioned.

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone else has this same problem I thought I would share my solution, because I couldn't find any Saiku specific answer anywhere else.

After struggling for a few hours, getting the error "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'TableName'.", I found that the correct way, or at least the one that worked for me, to specify the database name, was to add the jdbc prefix to the databaseName parameter.

This is my working example:

```
type=OLAP
name=foodmart
driver=mondrian.olap4j.MondrianOlap4jDriver
location=jdbc:mondrian:Jdbc=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;jdbc.databaseName=foodmart;Catalog=res:foodmart/FoodMart.xml;JdbcDrivers=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver;
username=sa
password=sa
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I've spent 2 hours digging into this problem and finally figured it out 80% of the way ;-) which led me to this post for the other 20% ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just use google:

http://docs.analytical-labs.com/DataSources.html

FYI You'll probably get quicker responses on Saiku questions if you use the IRC channel ##saiku on Freenode, or ask.analytical-labs.com

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to migueletes spent hours trying to find the solution.
My problem was to try to include the instanceName parameter to connect the hub to a cluster mssql and actually had to add the parameter jdbc.instanceName to it was taken into account, otherwise omit the parameter.

https://groups.google.com/a/saiku.meteorite.bi/forum/#!topic/user/q9_5OG6_wrw